# Turn a vector's indexes into its content and vice-versa

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, octave

I'm looking an efficient way to turn the vector:

```
[1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,1]
```

into a vector of vectors such that:

```
[[1,2,3,12],[4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10],[11]]
```

In general:

```
newVector[i] = indexes of the initial vector that contained i
```

Preferably in Matlab/Octave but I'm just curious if there is an efficient way of achieving this.

I tried looking it up on google and stack but I have no idea what to call this 'operation' so nothing came up.

Comment: Demonstrate that you've given it a try by writing the code yourself using a `for`-loop

Comment: Can you guarantee that all values will be from 1:n? Or can the original vector be `[1 2 10 2]`?

Comment: I was willing to accept empty vectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an easy way to do it using `accumarray`

```
A = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,1]
accumarray(A',A',[],@(x){find(ismember(A,x))})
```

But next time, please show your own attempt in your question

Alternatively (but only if `A` starts from `1` and doesn't skip any numbers)

```
accumarray(A', (1:size(A,2))', [], @(x){sort(x)})
```

Comment: Thanks. And you're right, I should have posted some code but I'm new to matlab and couldn't think of a way at the time.